# Pandas: Merge 2 dataframes based on a column values; for mulitple rows containing same column value, append those to different columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, dataframe1 and dataframe2. They both share the same data in a particular column for both, lets call this column  'share1' and 'share2' for dataframe1 and dataframe2 respectively.

The issue is, there are instances where in dataframe1 , there is only one row in 'share1' with a particular value (lets call it 'c34z'), but in dataframe2 there are multiple rows with the value  'c34z' in the  'share2' column.

What I would like to do is, in the new merged dataframe, when there are new values, I would just like to place them in a new column.

So the number of columns in the new dataframe will be the maximum number of duplicates for a particular value in 'share2' . And for rows where there was only a unique value in 'share2', the rest of the added columns will be blank, for that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using `cumcount` create the additional key then, `pivot` df2

```
newdf2=df2.assign(key=df2.groupby('share2').cumcount(),v=df2.share2).pivot_table(index='share2',columns='key',values='v',aggfunc='first')
```

After this ,I am using `.loc` or `reindex` `concat` `df2` to `df1`

```
df2=df2.reindex(df1.share1)

df2.index=df1.index
yourdf=pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
```

Comment: I'm getting an `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable` error when I run the 2nd line `df2=df2.reindex[df1.share1]`

Comment: @SantoshGupta7 that is the best I can do , base on my imagination ......since you didn’t provide the sample data also for fixed the error change []to ()

Comment: is df2 supposed to be newdf2 in the last three lines?

Answer (score 1):

Loading Data:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = {'key': ['c34z', 'c34z_2'], 'value': ['x', 'y']}
df2 = {'key': ['c34z', 'c34z_2', 'c34z_2'], 'value': ['c34z_value', 'c34z_2_value', 'c34z_2_value']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
```

Convert df2 by grouping and pivoting

```
df2_pivot = df2.groupby('key')['value'].apply(lambda df: df.reset_index(drop=True)).unstack().reset_index()
```

merge df1 and df2_pivot

```
df_merged = pd.merge(df1, df2_pivot, on='key')
```

Comment: is there way to expand this for multiple value columns?

Comment: @SantoshGupta7 can you please provide sample data